# Laravel Filter Query results based on URL Parameters

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

**The issue:**

How do I pass the following values to the URL. It would also need to have the ability to pass both, the date option and category to the URL, so I can handle it in the controller with the `$request->query('')` I cannot figure out how to do this?

I have the following Controller:

```
public function allCoursesList(Request $request)
{
    if (empty($request->query())) {
        return view('pages.all-events', [
            'events' => Events::query()
                ->where('start', '>', now())
                // add pagination
                ->paginate(15)

        ]);
    } else {
        return view('pages.all-events', [
            'events' => Events::query()
                ->where('category', $request->query('category'))
                ->where('start', '>', now())
                // add pagination
                ->paginate(15)

        ]);
    }
}
```

and I have my filter blade:

```
<form class="container">
    <div class="bg-custom-gray p-6 rounded-lg">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-6">
            <div>
                <div class="mb-3">Kategorie</div>
                <select class="w-full  p-3 rounded-lg">
                    <option value="0">Lorem Impsum</option>
                    <option value="1">Lorem Impsum</option>
                    <option value="2">Lorem Impsum</option>
                    <option value="3">Lorem Impsum</option>
                    <option value="4">Lorem Impsum</option>
                    <option value="5">Lorem Impsum</option>
                    <option value="6">Lorem Impsum</option>
                    <option value="7">Lorem Impsum</option>
                    <option value="8">Lorem Impsum</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="mb-3">Zeitbereich</div>
                <select class="w-full p-3 rounded-lg">
                    <option>Anstehend</option>
                    <option>Heute</option>
                    <option>Morgen</option>
                    <option>Diese Woche</option>
                    <option>Dieses Wochenende</option>
                    <option>Nächste Woche</option>
                    <option>Nächster Monat</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <x-button type="submit" class="mt-6 w-full">Suchen</x-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

based on the controller I can pass my category to the query with e.g. `example.com/loremimpsum?category=1`

Comment: your inputs have no name attribute

Comment: @lagbox you are absolutely correct.  That fixed my issue. It is always the small things that get overlooked. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused because the `<select>` was missing a [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-name) value.
So by adding `name="category"`

```
<select name="category" class="w-full  p-3 rounded-lg">
    <option value="0">Lorem Impsum</option>
    <option value="1">Lorem Impsum</option>
    <option value="2">Lorem Impsum</option>
    <option value="3">Lorem Impsum</option>
    <option value="4">Lorem Impsum</option>
    <option value="5">Lorem Impsum</option>
    <option value="6">Lorem Impsum</option>
    <option value="7">Lorem Impsum</option>
    <option value="8">Lorem Impsum</option>
</select>
```

I get the wanted URL parameter for the controller. Thank you very much for this info @lagbox